# How to read rows and columns via awk with special character separator

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Can this be done more easily in a single command?

Read line 10 and column 2 from the file where the separator is ^

```
cat file | awk 'FNR==10 {print}' | awk -v  FS=^ '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `^` is the main/common field separator for all records - it's enough to apply the following ***awk*** expression:

```
awk -F'^' 'NR==10{ print $2; exit }' file
```